# How do I add thickness to a 2D image in 3D space? Libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I want to add a **thickness/depth** to a 2d image. I've tried using a **DecalBatch**, but it produced this result: [Unwanted Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4EoQ.jpg)

However, I was expecting this result instead (viewed from the other side): [Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dROnd.jpg)

*One side works, the other doesn't*

The way I did it was detecting the edges using a **Pixmap** and manually creating *decals* for every pixel at the edge, which may be slow.

Are there other possible (faster) ways I can do this?

Comment: Maybe just draw multiple copies of your decal offset along their Z? You could do the math to calculate their spacing along the Z relative to the angle between the camera axis and the decal Z axis to get it to show only the edge pixels. This would involve a lot of overdraw though (pixels drawn multiple times uselessly because they cover each other).

Comment: Possibly to improve this performance you could create a mesh of your sprite that has the middle hollowed out so those pixels are not drawn to screen uselessly when you draw multiple copies of it. DecalBatch can only handle rectangles, so you'd either need to use the complicated 3D API, or you could use the FlexBatch library, which can handle batching PolygonSprites and regular rectangles together. But creating the PolygonSprite with the middle cutout would be a huge task to program. I wouldn't attempt it unless you have a true performance problem you have to fix.

Comment: If you are using OpenGL 3, you could use a geometry shader to extrude your sprites when you draw them. But you would definitely need to switch from rectangles to meshes that perfectly follow the contour of your sprite. I have no experience with geometry shaders.

Comment: I think TenFour04 is right in his first comment. Having said that if you want a 3d model you may as well drop Decals and go to 3d because you can create the models easily enough from textures https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-J_-3JLXpE

Comment: @londonBadger I would do that, but the decals are from arbitrary 2d textures, so I can't make 3d models in Blender. Sorry for not clarifying that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who've given their suggestions.

I've managed to fix it by reversing the decal array, which holds the decals, when the camera views the other side.

Some decals were hidden probably because of the arrangement of the decals when it's being rendered!

Anyways, here's the final result:
[FINAL RESULT :D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4PFm.jpg)

And here's the code which fixed it (Kotlin):

```
reversed = if (totalAngle % 360.0f < 180.0f) {
    if (!reversed) decals.reverse()
    true
} else {
    if (reversed) decals.reverse()
    false
}
/*reversed variable is used so that the
decals aren't reversed multiple times*/
```

Comment: I'm very interested in how this has gone for you because I write a game in 2D which is 3d space as far as the camera is concerned and the -only- reason its not low poly is because there is only one of me and I can't do the code and the low poly stuff. It seems to me that adding one decal per texture pixel would be extremely expensive because most decals need to be sorted internally. If you have any details you'd like to share please go on. I could ask a question "how to add per pixel mapped decals in libgdx".